# What are ways for a renaissance culture to combat my invasive species?

Tags: biology, aliens, ecology, low-fantasy, renaissance

My world is on the verge of being overrun by animals and plants from other planets that are well-adapted. Some of these creatures are magical in nature and more powerful and long-lived than the native life on my planet.

There are plants that overrun local crops and animals that mess up the local food chain. It can be comapared to the world of Half-Life 2 with all the Xen wildlife.

I have several governments that have mostly renaissance era technology.

How do they combat the rise of these invasive species.

**EDIT:**

SOme of the species that made their way here include:

- An arthropod like creature. While non-sapient, it instinctually captures breeding pairs of its prey, raises and breeds them for food. It creates or makes use of existing spaces to use as farms.Physically strong and large in size, it has been known to keep humans occasionally in its farms. It competes with humans by stealing livestock. Mostly carnovirous in diet, though the main threat is the theft of livestock and use of grazing land
- Ape-like creatures that are capable of some tool use that reproduce in great numbers. They are carnivorous and hunt regularly to feed themselves. They are adapted toward cold frigid environments and now find themselves in the mixed biome continent which includes tundras, taigas, and glacial areas.
- Pillbug shaped creatures that retain water and reproduce quickly. they blur the line between fungus and animal. They originate from a world where water is relatively scarce. Their main threat is their drinking water and entering a state of dormancy in hard to reach places like trees and mountains.

What methods are accessible to a renaissance era civilization that has yet to develop advanced and easily manufactured firearms?

What can be done given assumed scientific knowhow at the time?

Comment: There are many ways to fight invasive species.  Unfortunately, they differ according to the specifics.  The best way to fight songbirds is not the best way to fight scavengers which is not the best way to fight vines.  I think you will have to break this question down.

Comment: even today many has hard time to counter invasive species, outside of bringing their natural predator and hopping it dont bother the native species. either way lets the nature uh, finds a way as said by Jeff Goldburn (probably) its futile to play God afterall.

Comment: Please edit the question. 
We need to know the specifications of those animals and plants. 
It's like asking I'm fighting a war against an army and need to counter them.
Well. Give us the full rundown of your own forces and the estimated numbers of the enemies and we can make strategies.
After all: "If you know the enemy and know yourself, you need not fear the result of a hundred battles"
So. Please try to provide more details and other important information

Comment: This is what we call a "[high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609)." You have a neat idea, but you haven't developed it and you want us to do all the work. That's too broad. Remember, SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. Whole books can be (and have been) written about this subject just from a terrestrial POV. Fiction has been written, too (see the *[Deathworld Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld)* by Harry Harrison). There are hundreds of details needed to get to an objective answer. VTC:Opinion-Based.

Comment: @JBH I have a set of species to discuss. I just kind of rushed this out here. sorry. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can humans eat any of them? Or is their flesh-or-equivalent poisonous to us? We eat snails and squid and gelatin and bird eggs and all kinds of gross stuff. "*Kids, go down to the shore and gather up a basket of fungus-bugs for the casserole!*"

Comment: @user535733 Some of them may be edible(I had not thought of that), but I'm not sure if demand can keep up with the supply given how often the latter two reproduce.

Comment: Well, that's up to you. If they taste good, I can envision whole towns beating the wetlands every day for free yummy fungus-bugs. Watch out for overly-rapid reproduction: That's how you run into environmental collapse and extinction crises.

Comment: As long as humans have organizational skills and large individuals of an alien species to wipe out, the best way of killing them is to find a useful part of the animal and offering a bounty for it. Human ingenuity will come up with thousands of ways to root them out and destroy them once there is a profit motive. Even just offering a head bounty will motivate hunters to stalk and kill the aliens everywhere they go.

Comment: Viruses are incapable of replicating on their own and very fastidious about their hosts. Locate the alien native environment and isolate viruses that infect them. Nothing on Earth will be an animal-fungus hybrid, and releasing the viruses into contaminated water supplies will wipe out the poor pillbug population rapidly, as the quickly breeding bugs spread the viruses, and the resting ones maintain a reservoir of infected individuals.

Comment: Most likely, there will be biochemical differences that show up, so you can derive a variety of toxins and enzymes that attack these creatures. Such toxins will be like antibiotics but better. The wider the differences between two organisms, the more lethal the chemicals that will poison your aliens but leave terrestrial life unaffected. Who knows? Maybe ape-men can't take high magnesium. dropping magnesium-containing bait will poison them, but leave wolves unaffected (or possibly healthier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire, castles, poison and chemistry, other animals.

**Fire**

I mean you won't have renaissance style flamer squads but you can use fire. Good old fire really made us the masters of the planet and to this day people lost in the wild still make fire as like the number 1 thing to do in that situation.

The good part is that because of our engineering was can surpass even the little water retaining animals as we can use a crap ton of fuel, that is a very scientific term by the way, because we can use containers will biological life forms are stuck with biological limits. You also seem to follow biology and not say: the are bread for war so biology sucks. Or rather our engineering is amazing.

So. Basically humans use fire all the time to fight those things. I think I read a story about something similar in the world of Warhammer 40K with this city or compound using fire **all** the time to push back the jungle.

Well that world has tech I still think the idea hold merit. You just configure it whatever way you like.

Cities have fight making squads or volunteer fire makers...etc.
Hey. Pyromaniacs are very happy in that world. They get to do their thing and get paid. Yay.

Heck. You can even do it on the go. Cavalry are trained and prepared to use fire as a crown control method.

And remember real predators are very cowardly. As far as I know you can scare a frigging bear with a flare gun. Never mind putting your automatic rifles on full auto and giving the bear 30 rounds of lead in the face. A flare gun or something similar can scare animals. Predators are not suicidal creatures.

So. Even for mobile or traveling people you merely need to scare the things by showing overwhelming force and noise.

**Castles**

A good old castle is amazing against humans and even your wildlife. The reaons being it is a force multiplier. Your defenders can merely use gravity to attack the animals. All from the safety of the high walls.

Boiling water, hot sand, lime, oil...etc were all used to repel attackers.
And if they fail just pick up a rock and left gravity do the killing.

You can also create castles of such smooth walls that it is very difficult for creatures to climb it.

Also castles can be surrounded by water as we all know. And they are usually done on top of a hill or something so you can see the enemy coming a mile away.

**All this applies to other fortifications as well, just follow the established rules.**

And for the love of [Shad](https://www.youtube.com/user/shadmbrooks), add machicolations!

**Poison and chemistry**

I really think that in that situation people will work extra hard to figure out more about chemistry and try to combat them using primitive CBRN.

A special forces squad... I mean a bunch of knights go the enemy lands and poison their water wells.

Large scale military operation to destroy their natural habitat and poison it.

Large scale military operation to deprive them of valuable resources...etc.

chemistry is pretty easy as well. Maybe a good chemist can come up with a very strong poison against them that is harmless to humans. Maybe the develop and weaponize pesticides.

**Other animals**

You know those furry little adorable creatures that do nothing but require attention, feeding, and playing with?

Apparently back in the day they did stuff for us. I mean my cats would find the prospect horrifying.

But they did work for us. And in exchange were given food and shelter until it became absolute luxury for nothing deal.

Anyway we also have wolves evolving into dogs. Dogs which we later specialized into specific types to the point of having dogs that really help in hunting bears or lions or wolves...etc.

So. Maybe we will continuously work on current breads of animals to maximum their efficiency in that.

That can be a global thing. Every city has dog hunting squads and most humans have a dog that is pretty good in defending against the aliens. This is sort of anti infiltration stuff but it is common.

Rome had fire fighting squads and historically speaking we would gather and repel the wolves if they bothered the village or tribe.
The applications are many.

**Bonus: Armored war elephants**.

Armored war elephants using the best renaissance era weaponized fire and anti bugs things to fire the aliens, or molotov cocktails.

First of all no sane person would refuse to see or hear about such a cool concept.
That is pure awesome sauce.

Jokes aside. I actually can see the usage of war elephants in that situation.
Actual cavalry needed to be maneuverable and fast. Even heavy armored knights of cataphracts still needed to march long distances and be able to provide cavalry actions which include scouting or flanking or chasing skirmishers...etc. That is way they never replaced cavalry , also scarcity.

So. Here is were our elephants come in. They are a giant armored fist against the bugs. You are not worried about the enemy out smarting you, if you get out smarted by bugs then honestly not much can be said for that state as a whole.
We joke about stupid generals in history but at least they faced humans with warfare theory and all that.

Yeah. Just armored the hell out of the elephants and used it to constantly distrust the enemy lines and staying moving while the humans at the back throw molotov cocktails or even regular bottles of alcohol after they take a sip or ten. I mean the drunkenness makes the experience all the better.

I'm focusing on crowd control methods as it makes more sense. Stuff like bows or crossbows or wardarts...etc would be better than weapons made to counter human infantry armed with spears.

But honestly just giant war elephants fighting Kaiju I mean bugs seems pretty awesome and, I know it sounds insane but it is historical actually, practical.

Answer (score 1):

1. Arthropods have farms.  They will be easy to find.  Groups of humans will find them and kill them.
2. Apeman young will be raised by humans and trained.  These captive raised ones will be taught that they are better than the wild ones.  They will be bigger too because of better diet, and also well equipped.  Domesticated apes will then be used to wipe out their wild counterparts.  They can help wipe out the arthropod things too if the humans are busy.  Domesticated apes will be good for other things too.  Reproduction will be carefully controlled, as with other domestic animals.
3. Fungus bugs do not sound like a big deal if the main thing they want to do is drink water and go to sleep.  They might clutter up the place.  Not sure why these need to go.

Comment: The bugs reproduce quickly. If they become too prevalent then water in non-replenishing sources like lakes or ponds gets reduced and the water is now in harder to access locations.